# How to write $.fn.functionName = (function() { in jQuery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have lots of functions like: `$.fn.functionName = (function() {`

I call them using: `$(this).functionName();`

This is deprecated in jQuery 3, how can I rewrite the function definition in order to make it work well (just like before).

Do you know a Library that is able to (automatically) replace the deprecated jQuery sintax? There's the jquery migration tool: https://blog.jquery.com/2016/05/19/jquery-migrate-1-4-1-released-and-the-path-to-jquery-3-0/ but it doesn't help me too much.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Example log from jQuery 3 migration tool:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.focus() event shorthand is deprecated

console.trace()

migrateWarn
jQuery.fn[name]
$.fn.functionName/this.initData
$.fn.functionName
<anonymous>
_onReady
$.obj
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide a reference to this "deprecation" of creating jQuery add-on functions.

Comment: As above - why do you think this format is deprecated?

Comment: To answer both questions: because it doesn't work. These functions aren't evaluated. If I add a console log in one of this functions it won't be executed. I will update my question with a jquery 3 migration tool log.

Comment: Might be better to update your question with a small example of your non-working code.  see [mcve].

Comment: No, it does work perfectly well. I'm on jQuery 3.2.0 and I've got *lots* of add-on methods. They're all done in exactly that way.

Comment: Example of it working perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/qr4f7mb9/

Comment: Pointy, I tried using jquery 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and now I work with the latest one, jquery 3.3.1 . All of them have the same issues.

Comment: Are you using `.on` or `.trigger` ?

Comment: Yes I am, I use "on" in this case.

Comment: You can't use $(this).on('click', function()); in jquery 3?

Comment: It's not `$.fn.xxx` that's deprecated, but something you're using inside it.  If you can't provide the code, then comment all the code out and add it back line by line to show the issue.

Comment: You *can* use deprecated events - they're deprecated not removed.  It means they might be removed in a future version, but should work fine.  Are you having any other issues other than jqmigrate warnings?

Comment: You are right, I will remove the question. My question is totally wrong. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for answering. There was another deprecated function. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the source of the jqmigrate that you're using as this is not a warning in the version I found `jQuery Migrate - v1.4.1 - 2016-05-19`

Comment: Sure: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-migrate

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `jQuery.fn.blur() to jQuery.fn.trigger('blur')` and `jQuery.fn.focus() to jQuery.fn.trigger('focus')` as per this https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea/issues/217,

Comment: Good answer, thank you. This will fix other issues from my website. But the current issue is that I call the function on a "livequery" event. It's an old code..

Answer (score 0):

I was using the "livequery" (https://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/) and inside it I was calling the $.fn.functionName.

I know, it's an old code, but that was the problem. As freedomn-m said in a comment, the $.fn.xxx is not deprecated. I hope this will help others too.